# MATLAB IF VALUE LESS THAN

Tags: list, matlab, comparison

Hi I am writing a matlab code at the moment. I am trying to compare the values in a list to the number 10 and if the value is less than 10 add 1 to the total. However I cannot seem to get the code right. My code so far

```
tot = 0
for i=1:n
 if(x(i)<10)
  tot = +1
 else
  y=0;
 end
end

tot
```

The value I get for tot always = 1 and never increases? Can someone help edit this or if not provide a solution to the problem?

Comment: `tot = tot + 1` is the correct form. `t = +1` just sets `t` equal to `1` and doesn't increase it.

Comment: @Sadjad I see so by not adding tot + 1 t would just take the value of 1 everytime if the value is less than 10 right?

Comment: @Sadjad thanks it is a simple solution that I shold have realised but I mustn't have been looking to hard :) Thanks again

Comment: You're totally welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

I would agree with the answer mentioned above, that one should avoid for loops for this. There  can be a faster solution. Since, he is just interested in the counts, and not value of numbers, so there is no need to index things back.

Given:

```
 a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
```

Computing numbers less than 10 (you could put any number here)

```
answer = sum(a<10);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In languages like MATLAB and R, you *really* should not use `for` loops like this, even as an exercise. Each variable can be a vector, and operations can occur on the whole vector at once, rather than element-by-element.

Given:

```
x = [ 1 2 3 4 11 12 13 14 15 16 ]
```

To generate a list of all `x` less than 10 you would say:

```
x(x<10)
```

So to count them:

```
total = length(x(x<10))
```

No loop needed or wanted!